# Laravel Excel generate several times a template in a single file

Tags: laravel, maatwebsite-excel, laravel-excel

I'm using Laravel Excel, and I have actually a template which I use to generate invoices like this :

```
 public function registerEvents(): array
    {
      return [
         BeforeExport::class => function(BeforeExport $event){
            $excelFile = $event->writer->reopen(new LocalTemporaryFile(storage_path('app/contracts/template.xls')),Excel::XLS);

            //// Invoice Sheet
            $invoiceSheet = $event->writer->getSheetByIndex(0);
            
            $spreadsheet = $invoiceSheet->getDelegate();
            $spreadsheet->setShowGridLines(false);

            // Invoice Number and Date
            $invoiceSheet->setCellValue("L3", $this->invoiceDetails["invoiceNumber"]);
            $invoiceSheet->setCellValue("I5", $this->invoiceDetails["invoiceDate"]);
........
return $excelFile;
         }
      ];
}
```

This single export is working fine, I update my template with my dynamic data and I finally generate the file.

But now I would like to generate 2 invoices with the same template with 2 different set of dynamic values.

If I simply add a loop in my registerEvent function I will only receive the last set since it will overwrite the previous set of data.

How can I acheive that ? I could generate 2 different files, reopen them and merge them into a single file that my endpoint could return but that seems a bit uneffective.
Is it possible, during the generation process to duplicate my template everytime need it and then generate my file in a single call?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You could save them to different sheets in the one excel file. I know Laravel Excel supports multiple sheets.

Comment: I know it supports multiple sheets since this is what i'm doing actually (updating 2 different sheets from my template). But actually I just update several sheets from my template, what I would like to do is duplicating a sheet several times in my file.